# assembly code have a mistake Run-Time Check Failure

Tags: assembly, x86, calling-convention, fastcall

I have a Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call. This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.
This my code

```
extern "C" int __fastcall Proc5(int* arr, int* freq, int raznost, int n, int N, int* result_5);
int main() {
    const int N = 3;//2000; // количество элементов для подсчета количества значений
    int raznost = N / 2; // рассчитывается смещение для отрицательных чисел
    int arr[] = { 0,1};
    int freq[N] = { 0 };
int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
int* result_5 = new int[n];
Proc5(arr, freq, raznost, n, N, result_5);
cout << "Proc5" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    std::cout << result_5[i] << " ";
}
```

```
@Proc5@24 proc
        



        xor eax, eax
        xor ebx, ebx
        ;xor ecx, ecx
        ;xor edx, edx
        mov eax, ecx
        mov ebx, edx
        mov edx, [esp + 4]
        
        ;mov edi, [esp + 8]
        ;;;
        push ebx
        
        imul edx, 4
        
        add ebx, edx
        xor ecx, ecx
        
        loop_1 :
        cmp ecx, [esp + 12]
            je loopend_1
            mov edx, [eax + ecx * 4]
            inc dword ptr [ebx + edx * 4]
            inc ecx
            jmp loop_1
            loopend_1 :
        pop ebx 
            xor edx, edx ; для количества элементов в новом массиве
            xor ecx, ecx
            outer_loop :
        cmp ecx, [esp + 8]
            je outer_loopend
            push ecx
           
            xor ecx, ecx ; счетчик
            xor eax, eax ; максимальное значение
            xor esi, esi ; количество
            mov eax, 0
            loop_2:
            
        cmp ecx, [esp + 16]
            je loopend_2
            cmp esi, [ebx + ecx * 4]
            jg end_if
            mov esi, [ebx + ecx * 4]
            mov eax, ecx
            end_if :
            inc ecx
            jmp loop_2
            loopend_2 :
        xor ecx, ecx
            push ebx
            mov ebx, eax
            push ebx
            mov ebx, [esp + 28]
            sub eax, [esp + 16]
            loop_3 :
        cmp esi, ecx
            je loopend_3
            mov[ebx + edx * 4], eax
            inc edx
            inc ecx
            jmp loop_3
            loopend_3:
        pop ebx
            mov edi, ebx
            pop ebx
            push eax
            mov eax, 0
            mov [ebx + edi * 4], eax
            pop eax
            pop ecx
            ;push ebp
            inc ecx
            jmp outer_loop
            outer_loopend:


    

    ret 
@Proc5@24   endp
```

this is a program for sorting an array by the frequency of occurrence of elements

Comment: If your function is `stdcall`, you need to remove the arguments from the stack when returning (use `ret <n>`).

Comment: 32-bit fastcall is still a callee-pops convention, and you still have 4 stack args so you need `ret 16` instead of the `ret 24` you needed with stdcall before your edit.  It's not a coincidence that 24 is the same number as in the symbol name `Proc5@24`

Answer (score 0):

This comment help me.
32-bit fastcall is still a callee-pops convention, and you still have 4 stack args so you need ret 16 instead of the ret 24 you needed with stdcall before your edit. It's not a coincidence that 24 is the same number as in the symbol name Proc5@24 –
Peter Cordes